# EACCES permission denied error after Spark AR latest update

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

Recently Spark AR got updated and all my effects using scripts get this error now:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/Users/user/Library/Caches/Facebook/Spark AR Studio/Projects.../ script.js ->  '/Users/rbkavin/Library/Caches/Facebook/Spark AR Projects/.../app/script.js {
"line": 1
"column": 16
"sourceURL": "file:///" }
```

Even when I create a completely new project and create a script I immediately get this error in the console. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Working on MacOS Mojave, the issue started to appear after the last Spark AR update.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it fixes the error forever, but restarting Spark AR fixed it. Anyway, I have experienced all kind of bugs and errors that get fixed after relaunch, so make yourself a favour and save the project :)

Also a guy on facebook commented me that this is a very common issue on macOS Mojave and Catalina and disabling “com.apple.quarantine” should do the job.

p.s. if you know any forum or place where we could suggest auto save, please comment on it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that after giving Full Disk Access to the Spark AR Studio.
For that, Go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy. Then select the Privacy Tab. Scroll down to Full Disk Access and Add Spark AR Studio from the "+" button.